# Bash get-hardware script output to .csv file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, centos

I'm using the following script to get server hardware info:

https://pastebin.com/5Um4Bir6

The code below is just a part of it (as StackOverflow recommends)

```sh
echo
echo -e "+++++++++++++++++++ \e[1;34m SYSTEM \e[0m+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
echo
lshw -c system -short |sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g'| cut -d' ' -f2-100 |grep -v "=" |grep -v Desc |grep -v PNP |sed 's/system //g'
echo
echo -e "+++++++++++++++++++ \e[1;34m CPU \e[0m +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
echo
lshw -c processor -short |grep -v "=" |grep -v Desc |sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g'| cut -d' ' -f2-100 |sed 's/processor //g'
echo
echo -e "+++++++++++++++++++ \e[1;34m MEMORY \e[0m ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
echo
lshw -c memory -short |grep -v "=" |grep -v Desc |grep -v empty |grep -v cache |sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g'| cut -d' ' -f2-100 |sed 's/memory //g' |grep DIMM
```

I'm using this script on Ubuntu 18.04.03 and CentOS 7 boxes and I need help to get the output to a .csv file.
And the output should be like the header that has SYSTEM, CPU, MEMORY, etc. The respective columns should have the output of the commands like `lshw`, `ethtool`, `nvidia-smi`, etc.

Comment: Just >> out.csv however your question isn't correct. Why would you want half of that echo'd into a csv? What are you trying to 'save'?

Comment: I need to save the header, that has SYSTEM, CPU, MEMORY and so on. And the output of the commands like lshw, ethtool, etc in the respective columns.

Comment: Generally, `grep | grep | sed | grep | cut` is an anti-pattern, that is better expressed with `awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using command grouping by using curly braces `{ }` and `>>` redirection.

```
{
echo
echo -e "+++++++++++++++++++ \e[1;34m SYSTEM \e[0m+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
echo
lshw -c system -short |sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g'| cut -d' ' -f2-100 |grep -v "=" |grep -v Desc |grep -v PNP |sed 's/system //g'
echo
echo -e "+++++++++++++++++++ \e[1;34m CPU \e[0m +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
echo
lshw -c processor -short |grep -v "=" |grep -v Desc |sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g'| cut -d' ' -f2-100 |sed 's/processor //g'
echo
echo -e "+++++++++++++++++++ \e[1;34m MEMORY \e[0m ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
echo
lshw -c memory -short |grep -v "=" |grep -v Desc |grep -v empty |grep -v cache |sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g'| cut -d' ' -f2-100 |sed 's/memory //g' |grep DIMM
} >> file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed.